# Reac-navigation 5 with AuthContext and 2 Stack Navigator : loop and flash screens

Tags: expo, react-navigation-v5

Here is the main app (Expo sdk36 with react-navigation 5) :

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer
        onStateChange={(stateNavigation) => console.log('New stateNavigation is', stateNavigation, state)}
      >
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            {state.isLoading ? (
              <Stack.Screen name="Loading" component={AppLoadingScreen} />
            ) : state.profile === null ? (
              // No status, user isn't signed in
              <Stack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} />
            ) : (
              // User is signed in
              <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
</Provider>
```

SignInScreen and HomeScreen are ScreenNavigator :

```
function SignInScreen() {
    const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn">
          {(props) => <SignIn {...props} signIn={signIn} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function HomeScreen() {
    const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home">{(props) => <Home {...props} />}</Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile">
          {(props) => <Profile {...props} signOut={() => signOut()} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
```

It starts with SignIn, I log in, it goes to Home, I select the Profile button and it refreshes the Profile Screen indefinitely. I can click on the SignOut button and it goes to SignIn Screen (with few flashes again here).
The full log of stateNavigation and state is here : https://gist.github.com/lc3t35/d32d5ef6d042fec4c1344fbe9769b06b

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Can you share your full code? It's not possible to know what's happening without looking at what's in your components.

Comment: @satya164 Of course no, I can't share full code otherwise I would have put a full repo available ;) It's a migration from React Navigation 4. So based on what you've seen above, nothing seems to be wrong at this level ?

Comment: No need to share your full code, share your Profile component, since this is where it's starting. And no, nothing seems obviously wrong so far. Also, not such a good idea to share your logs like this, could have shared some sensitive data, even if it's on development.

Answer (score 0):

Between `<Provider>` and `<AuthContext.provider>`, I also have `<ReduxNetworkProvider>` from `react-native-offline`. It seems to trigger NavigationContainer props....
I removed it and the app behaves better (despite some suspect refresh still active...)
Digging more into this ....